# Quantifier range not working in lookbehind

Tags: php, regex, lookbehind, quantifiers

Okay so I'm working on a project where I need a regex that can match a * followed by 1-4 spaces or tabs and then followed by a row of text. Right now I'm using .* after the lookbehind for testing purposes. However I can get it to match explicitly 1, 2, or 4 spaces/tabs but not 1-4. I'm testing against the following block

```
*    test line here
*   Second test
*  Third test
* Another test
```

And these are the two patterns I'm testing `(?<=(\*[ \t]{3})).*` which works just as expected and matches the 2nd line, same if I replace 3 with 1, 2 or 4 however if I replace it with 1,4 forming the following pattern `(?<=(\*[ \t]{1,4})).*` it no longer matches any of the rows and I honestly can't understand why. I've tried googling without success. I'm using the g(lobal) flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP, like many flavors, doesn't support variable length lookbehind. The only support is *alternation* (`|`) at the top level of the lookbehind. Even a `?` can break the pattern. An alternative is to use:

```
(?<=\*[ \t]|\*[ \t]{2}|\*[ \t]{3}|\*[ \t]{4}).*
```

Or better, abort the lookbehind for a group:

```
\*[ \t]{1,4}(.*)
```

This should work well for you, since it doesn't seem like you have overlapping of your matches anyway.

From the manual:

> The contents of a lookbehind assertion are restricted such that all the strings it matches must have a fixed length. However, if there are several alternatives, they do not all have to have the same fixed length. Thus (?<=bullock|donkey) is permitted, but (?<!dogs?|cats?) causes an error at compile time. Branches that match different length strings are permitted only at the top level of a lookbehind assertion.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that the regex will still not do what the OP probably wants - it will gladly match more than 4 spaces because `.*` will match spaces just fine.

Comment: @Tim - That's a good point, but I think `.*` is just a simplified example of what the OP sees as an odd behavior - the interesting part is the look behind.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that. By the way, RegexBuddy doesn't complain about `{1,4}` (it balks at infinite quantifiers, but not at this finite quantifier).

Comment: After some testing with alternation it seem like it always will match only * followed by one space thus resulting in the matched area being starting with tabs or spaces, but I guess I could just abort the lookbehind group as you said and then with string manipulation remove the unnecessary space. I guess I could use substring to remove the first character and then ltrim. And yeah `.*` were just simplification because the lookbehind was what I wanted help with.

Comment: @Tim - I suppose it depends on the implementation: `{1,4}` can be expanded to a legal alternation, but PHP doesn't do it (which is better, of course, it might create a monstrosity). I check my PHP patterns at http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm , and sometimes on ideone, which I guess are closer to the real thing :)

Comment: @Hultner - note the capturing group I've added on the second regex - you can still get the line without the prefix. Try using `preg_match_all("/\*[ \t]{1,4}(.*)/", $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);` , and `$matches` will contain an array of arrays. The second item in each is the line without the asterisk and the leading spaces.

Comment: Hmm now I think i missed something. How'd php know that it should remove the asterisk and the leading spaces and not something else? Right now I'm using `preg_match_all("/^[*][ \t]{1,4}[ \w]{3,50}$/m")`

Comment: Never mind now I understand, by setting PREG_SET_ORDER it puts all the groups in their own element in the array. Thats actually really smart, that way everything outside of the group kinda works like lookbehinds and lookaheads.

Comment: @Hultner - Great to see you figured this up before I even had time to comment. Good luck! `:)`