# Regular Expressions, understanding lookbehind in combination with the or operator

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, regex-lookarounds

This is more a question of understanding than an actual problem. The situation explains as follows. I got some float numbers (e.g. an amount of money) between two quotation marks "".

Examples:

1. "1,23"
2. "12,23"
3. "123,23"

Now I wanted to match the comma in those expressions. I built the following regex which works for me:

```
(?<=\"[0-9]|[0-9]{2})(,)(?=[0-9]{2}\")
```

The part which I don't completly understand is the lookbehind in combination with the or "|". But let's break it up:

```
(
?<=             //Start of the lookbehind
\"              //Starting with an escaped quotation mark "
[0-9]           //Followed by a digit between 0 and 9
```

Now I had the problem, that after the quotation mark wasn't always just one digit as you can see in the examples 2 and 3. The range operator e.g. {1,3} did not work within the lookbehind. As I found out in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956360/quantifier-range-not-working-in-lookbehind) stackoverflow question.

So I decided to use the or "|" operator as sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings):

```
|[0-9]{2}       //Or followed by two digits between 0 and 9
)
```

The interesting part is that it also matches the comma in the third example "123,23". I don't really understand why.
Also I don't know why I don't have to add the starting quotation mark after the or "|" operator again, because I thought that the complete lookbehind until the or operator would be necessary to be modified or repeated e.g.:

```
(?<=\"[0-9]|\"[0-9]{2})(,)(?=[0-9]{2}\")            //This however does not work at all
```

So in my understanding the corresponding regular expression to match all three examples should look like the following:

```
(?<=\"[0-9]|\"[0-9]{2}|\"[0-9]{3})(,)(?=[0-9]{2}\")
```

or at least (if someone can explain the missing \"):

```
(?<=\"[0-9]|[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3})(,)(?=[0-9]{2}\")
```

I hope someone is able to help me understand the situation.

//Edit:
If it is of special interest, I used this regex in a regular textfile in the sublime text 3 editor, to search for the comma and replace it.

Comment: `(?<=\"[0-9]|[0-9]{2})` matches all the commas in these examples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct,

```
(?<=\"[0-9]|\"[0-9]{2}|\"[0-9]{3})(,)(?=[0-9]{2}\")
```

should be the right regex in this case.

---

About why you *"don't need the `\"` for two and three digits"* - you actually need it.

```
(?<=\"[0-9]|[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3})(,)(?=[0-9]{2}\")
```

Will match `12,23"` and `123,23"` as well.

---

**EDIT**:
Looks like the problem is that Sublime doesn't allow for variable length of lookbehind even if they are listed with `|`. Meaning `(?<=\"[0-9]|\"[0-9]{2}|\"[0-9]{3})` will fail, because the alternatives are not of the same size - *2, 3, 4*.

This is because Sublime seems to be using the [Boost library](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html#regular-expressions) regexes. [There](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.lookbehind) it is stated:

> Lookbehind
>
> `(?<=pattern)` consumes zero characters, only if pattern could be matched against the characters preceding the current position (**pattern must be of fixed length**).
>
> `(?<!pattern)` consumes zero characters, only if pattern could not be matched against the characters preceding the current position (**pattern must be of fixed length**).

An alternative is to separate the lookbehinds:

```
(?:(?<=\"[0-9])|(?<=\"[0-9]{2})|(?<=\"[0-9]{3}))(,)(?=[0-9]{2}\")
```

---

What can you do if you don't want to list all possible lengths?

There is a cool trick which is present in some regex engines (including Perl's, Ruby's and Sublime's) - `\K`. What `\K` roughly translates to is *"drop all that was matched so far"*. Therefore, you can match any `,` within a float number surrounded by quotation marks with:

```
"\d+\K,(?=\d+")
```

[See it in action](http://rubular.com/r/l0YUj8oy2y)

Comment: Well I mean that sublime text does not accept `(?<=\"[0-9]|\"[0-9]{2})(,)(?=[0-9]{2}\")` and says the following error: "Invalid lookbehind assertion encountered in the regular expression", same with `(?<=\"[0-9]|\"[0-9]{2}|\"[0-9]{3})(,)(?=[0-9]{2}\")`. But yes `"\d+\K,(?=\d+")` works just fine for that specific case. Thank you for that. Maybe it's just a problem of sublime text and not a problem of the regex itself?

Comment: If it's just a problem of sublime text, I can live with that. Thank you very much for this anwser. It helped my understanding a lot.

Comment: I did some further investigation and updated my answer to explain why Sublime has this limitation and how you can work around it.

Comment: Again, thank you for your effort. I really appreciate it.